# Is there a definition of the "Maclaurin Operator" in terms of simpler linear operators

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

We can unrigorously define the "Maclaurin Operator" $M$ as an operator that takes a holomorphic function as input and outputs a holomorphic function with the following (non unique) defining property: if $f$ is a holomorphic function that is defined around $0$ by the following taylor series

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $$

Then

$$ M[f] = a(x) $$

Example, if $f(x) = e^x$ then $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} x^n$ and therefore $$ M[e^x] = \frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}$$ See the note below for why this isn't unique.

Now regardless of which of the infinitely many Maclaurin operators you want to study there exists a linear subset. That is a set of Maclaurin operators such that: $M[f+g]= M[f]+ M[g]$. So naturally, it should be be possible to express the linear Maclaurin operators in the derivative basis that is

$$M[f]  = q_0(x) f + q_1(x) f' + q_2(x) f'' ... $$

For some suitable choice of complex functions $q_i(x)$

This leads us to the actual question, can someone find a closed form expression of a set of $q_i$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} q_i(x) f^{(i)}(x)$ is a linear $M$ operator?

### Lack of uniqueness...

In our $e^x$ case we took it for granted that $\frac{1}{n!}$ is the same as $\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)}$. It could very well have been that $\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{\cos(\pi n)^2}{\Gamma(n+1)}$ and so we could make that argument that there are at least two $M$ operators, (call them $M_1, M_2$ such that

$$M_1[e^x] = \frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)} $$

$$M_2[e^x]  = \frac{\cos(\pi x)^2}{\Gamma(x+1)} $$

of course its easy to see why there are many more than 2, so the basic premise then is that there are infinitely many ways to "interpolate" Taylor coefficients. I'm only interested in the "linear" variety of $M$ operators, and moreover, it would be nice if there was a way to describe a "simplest" or elementary $M$ operator but that seems difficult at the moment and therefore out of the scope of the question.

### Some More Connections:

There is an argument to be made that the "Maclaurin Operator" is a discrete version of the inverse mellin transform.

Comment: It seems that $f(x)$ is just the Z-transform of the sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ with $s_n=a_n, n\geq 0$ and $s_n=0, n<0$. Thus, recovering $s_n$ from $f(x)$ is done by the inverse Z-transform which is a contour integral, and $n$ can be extended the complex plane. Such contour integral is already a linear operator. Are you looking some way to express such integral as a linear combination of functions $q_i(x)$?

Comment: @FeedbackLooper silly me, yea i guess the next step then is to take that contour integral and break it up into $q_i$ acting on derivatives. I had vaguely heard of the Z-transform before but never knew what it was. This step might still be difficult given that I dont think i've ever decomposed a closed contour integral into a sum over derivatives.

Comment: I agree with the last part. I'm not sure if such decomposition can be done in the derivative basis. Sounds interesting... I'll keep this problem in mind.

Comment: Yea for non closed loops its usually possible to squish around and adjust the result $f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x)+... = e^x \int_{c}^{x} e^{-s} f(s) ds $  to work.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure if this answers your question but the Maclaurin operator is defined through differentiation operator $D$ which is formally:

$$e^{tD}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}D^n= id + \frac{t}{1!}D + \frac{t^2}{2!}D^2 + ...$$

which is giving

$$e^{tD}f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}D^nf^{(n)}= f + \frac{t}{1!} f' + \frac{t^2}{2!} f'' + ...$$

or Maclaurin is then:

$$f(t) =\left ( e^{tD}f \right)(0)$$

Taylor is then just a shift if you want to extend this.

**Edit:**

Above this, for continuous case, you have fractional derivative and integral alternative to Taylor series.

This is fractional derivative defined as an operator:

$$\left(D^\alpha f\right) ( x ) = \frac{ 1 }{ \Gamma ( \alpha ) } \int_0^x \left(x-t\right)^{\alpha-1} f(t) \, dt \,.$$

And here is Taylor

$$f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{D^tf(z_0)}{\Gamma(t+1)}(z-z_0)^t \, dt \,.$$

I do not think you can meaningfully go away from one of the two above.

Comment: hmm... this is actually pretty slick. i'm pondering if this can be modified to solve the problem i have asked.

Comment: ahh actually here is where things get confusing, is $t$ also the argument of $f$? because in that case $e^{tD} f_{t=0}$ will be just a constant. I think my edits did not respect what you intended to say.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas You edited it wrongly, $t$ is a free variable. differentiation goes over $x$ in $f(x)$.

Comment: I wrote Macluarian. Watched too many StarWars... sorry. Edited it now :)

Comment: Ok so... the formula doesn't give the Maclaurin operator at all, its just a change of variables now that i think about it. I.E. the way you wrote it originally was correct.  I don't know how to use this to solve the problem I have asked.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I do not think you should mix Maclaurin as it is discrete. It just leads you nowhere. What you need is fractional derivative defined as:

$$\left(D^\alpha f\right) ( x ) = \frac{ 1 }{ \Gamma ( \alpha ) } \int_0^x \left(x-t\right)^{\alpha-1} f(t) \, dt \,.$$